# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angular-material, angular6

I'am trying to get the keys and values from the firebase. Getting the keys and values and then storing in this.listData is my target. I have tried different ways, but none worked for me.Any solution appreciated.

Following are the files:

1. admin-products.component.ts

   ```
   listData: MatTableDataSource<any>;
     displayedColumns: string[] = ['title'];
     ngOnInit() {
       this.productService.getAll().subscribe(list => {
         let array =  list.map(c => 
           {
            return { $key: c.key, ...c.payload.val() }
           });
         this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(array);
         console.log("What is here ", this.listData);
       })}
   ```
2. admin-products.component.html

   ```
   <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
       <mat-table [dataSource]="listData">
           <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
               <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Title</mat-header-cell>
               <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"></mat-cell>
           </ng-container>
           <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedcolumns"></mat-header-row>
           <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
       </mat-table>
       <mat-table [dataSource]="listData">
           <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
               <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Title</mat-header-cell>
               <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"></mat-cell>
           </ng-container>
           <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedcolumns"></mat-header-row>
           <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
       </mat-table>
   ```

The error I'am getting is:

> Cannot read property 'val' of undefined.

My main goal is to get keys and values from firebase and populate it in Angular Material DataTable and then sort , filter, search the values. Do recommend any documentation or tutorial.

Comment: what is the result of `console.log(list);` before your `let array` statement?

Comment: It seems that `c.payload` is undefined when you call `c.payload.val()`. What is the `this.productService.getAll().subscribe(` that you're calling?

Comment: Ian Preglo... By doing console.log(list) I'am getting the keys and value but, how to store it in ths.listData and populate in Angular MatTable?

Comment: Frank van Puffelen... In this.productService.getAll().subscribe() I'am getting the data from Firebase via Service

Comment: @Pranav can you paste what it looks like, because the value of val will depend on this list

Comment: Check your  "...c.payload " by debugging.